# Creating animation when screen diomension can change- Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, animation, resize

I am trying to create animation which is based on user input on speed and distance... also it needs to work consistently on different screens and resolution

what functions do i use to get the pixel size of the container where the animation is playing- to make the calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

listen for keyboard events, like here http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/08/04/closing-a-pop-up-window-using-the-keyboard-in-flex/

get any UIComponent width and height by using:

```
blah=yourComponent.width
```

Comment: thanks... able to access these components properties in ActionScript w/o issues.

Comment: great, you know where to ask your questions to get correct answers, u r welcome)